# C creating a new type of int

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I know that the compiler supports some types like `__int128_t` on 64 bit architectures. It basically stores a number in 2 registers. Now, is there any way to create something like `__int256_t`, on a 64 bit machine?

Basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to extend the compiler to support a data type that stores a number on 4 registers, for example, and overload somehow the + operator to add them properly.

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? Why can't you use [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)? For what processor, what compiler (I guess GCC, since you tagged it), what operating system? For what source code? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: The question is meant just to improve my knowledge/understanding of the language and the compiler, without any practical result (it will actually be impractical to have a primitive data type stored on 4 registers or more). So i'm asking more from a theoretical point of view. Also, this can easily be achieved using a structure with 4 ints and functions to add/multiply. But again, the question is about making my new type to behave like a built-in one.

Comment: Are you prepared to spend weeks or months of work on that?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm prepared to spend a few days to understand how it might be done.

Comment: A few days won't be enough to understand....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably need to configure a new target for your compiler.

If thinking of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), try to patch the trunk (future GCC 5.0, to be released in spring 2015) since it has better support (see its  `gcc/wide-int.h` file) for so called wide ints. You'll probably also need to patch `gcc/config/i386/`, in particular some `*.md` -machine description- files.

Beware, it is a big lot of work (months). Can't you just use some [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) instead?

BTW, you'll need to define a new [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and new [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) too...

I would believe it is not worth the effort. A simpler work (still weeks of effort) might be to customize some optimization passes in GCC using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to help use of *GMPlib* (or of your `struct myint256_t`) perhaps thru additional builtins etc....

If you just want to play with some compiler to do that and don't care about performance, hack some much simpler compiler like [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git) or [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/)

A simpler project would be a translator from your dialect of C with 256 bits ints to some more ordinary C code (translating the `int256_t` to some `struct myint256_t` etc...). You might also have a look into languages with built-in support for [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), like [Common Lisp](https://common-lisp.net/) and its [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) implementation. Beware that efficient bignum arithmetic is algorithmically very tricky.

Notice that in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (and some earlier versions of C++) you can override the `operator +` to be able to write `a + b` (where both `a` and `b` are some instance of a complex `class` [mpz_class](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html) or your own one)

Comment: Another way would be to use `__int128_t [2]` or a 2 members struct but of course all the arithmetic operators would have to be re-implemented as functions or macros.

Comment: And one could help the optimization of these macros with some ad-hoc optimization pass coded in MELT...

Answer (score 3):

Not in C. Numeric data types are implemented in the compiler, and cannot be extended by applications.

This would be doable in C++, although the object would typically end up stored on the stack, not in registers.

Answer (score 3):

In C you're probably looking for something like the  [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library which allows you to have numbers of any size.

Physically adding it to the C compiler is possible, but it would be a lot of work and most people who would have an interest already use GMP or one of the many similar libraries.

If you want learn you might be better with the [Clue C Compiler](http://cluecc.sourceforge.net/) which uses [the Sparse parser](https://sparse.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) as it's frontend; they're a lot nicer than any 'real' C compiler.